# Could it be that a object has no mapping to its image by the endofunctor?

Tags: category-theory

I got confused when I saw $LR \to I$ in an Adjunction. The same goes for Comonad. For any object $a$ in Category $C$, $F a$ is the image of $a$ by endofunctor $F$.

Could a morphism $a \to F a$, not exist?

I know that a endofunctor maps all source objects in a domain. Then, for any object $a$, shouldn't $a \to F a$, which is the image of $a$ of endofunctor $F$, always exist?

Comment: Welcome to mse! I'm fairly confused by your question. A functor is a map between two categories, so $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$. Since $a \in \mathcal{C}$ is an object in $\mathcal{C}$, it doesn't make sense to ask for an arrow $a \to Fa$, since $Fa \in \mathcal{D}$. That said, in a programming context, often the word "functor" is used to mean in particular a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is the syntactic category of some type theory. In that case it makes sense to ask for an arrow $a \to F a$, but there's no reason for it to exist in general.

Comment: With all this in mind, would you please clarify what it is you're looking for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for writing without thinking. Functor in my question means endofunctor. I got confusion from Adjunction I -> R L , L R -> I . For L R -> I, L R c -> c exists. For L R c to exist, there would be a Functor L R mapping c to L R c for any c. Therefore, c -> L R c exists and I -> L R is automatically established. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the category of the ordered set $\mathbb{Z}$. The objects are the integers, and if $a$ and $b$ are integers, then the set of arrows from $a$ to $b$ is a singleton if $a\leq b$, and empty otherwise.

Let $F$ be the endofunctor mapping every integer $a$ to $a-1$. Then there is *never* an arrow from $a$ to $Fa$.